# EF Core FK Property Contains Ghost Element

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I load an object from the database like this:

```
Eingangsrechnung = db09.Eingangsrechnungen
    .Include(x => x.Baustelle)
    .Include(x => x.Lieferant)
    .Include(x => x.Eingangsrechnungsdokumente)
    .Include(x => x.Eingangsrechnungskategorie)
    .Include(x => x.Umsatzsteuersatz)
    .Include(x => x.Zahlungen)
    .Where(x => x.Zahlungen.Any(x => x.ORechnungsartFk == 2))
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DEgrId == id);
```

After the code is executed, the Eingangsrechnungsdokumente property contains 2 elements. The first of which is a blank/empty instance of Eingangsrechnungsdokumente.

[image]

However, the first item in the collection does not exist. When I print out the counts, the results show, that there is only one record in the database.

```
Debug.Print($"Count Eingangsrechnung.Eingangsrechnungsdokumente {Eingangsrechnung.Eingangsrechnungsdokumente.Count()}" );
//--> returns 2
Debug.Print($"Count Eingangsrechnungsdokumente for FK {db09.Eingangsrechnungensdokumente.Count(x=>x.OEingangsrechnungFK == id)}"); 
//--> returns 1
```

The Property in the parent is set up like this:

```
    [ForeignKey("OEingangsrechnungFK")]
    public virtual ICollection<TEingangsrechnungsdokumente> Eingangsrechnungsdokumente { get; set; }
```

How can I debug this further? Where is this empty instance coming from?

**1. Update as suggested by CF5**

Even after loading the record wihtout any include, the empty object is there.

```
Eingangsrechnung = db09.Eingangsrechnungen        
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DEgrId == id);
```

[image]

Comment: Can't see anything obvious there, is OEingangsrechnungFK declared as a property in your Eingangsrechnungen class?  If you could include the rest of the class it may help.

Personally I would trim the query back and perhaps try it in linqPad.  I'd start with

Eingangsrechnung = db09.Eingangsrechnungen
    .Include(x => x.Eingangsrechnungsdokumente)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DEgrId == id);

if possible and see if you get they same results there.  Then build back up if it is okay.

Comment: Thanks, please see update. There is no OEingangsrechnungFK Property in the Eingangsrechnungen class. I have the same code for another class, where it works fine.

Comment: I wonder if you have some rogue data in Eingangsrechnungsdokumente or any linking tables that you have between that and Eingangsrechnungen

Comment: Can I see your model? Maybe you populate it in constructor of `Eingangsrechnungen` ?